# Algorithm: find largest subset from arrays

Tags: arrays, algorithm, intersection

I have multiple arrays. I need to find the largest subset of arrays, such that, all arrays in that subset have atleast an element in common with each other.
By largest I mean, the subset should have most number of arrays. I am not interested in finding which particular arrays are in the subset, but rather the size of the subset.
e.g. if:

```
a1 = [1,3,7]
a2 = [3,5,7]
a3 = [2,8,9]
a4 = [7,8,9]
```

then I should get largest subset size as 3, because largest subset of given arrays would be `a1`,`a2` and `a4`, because:
a1 ∩ a2 != ∅ && a1 ∩ a4 != ∅ && a2 ∩ a4 != ∅

I have a function `common(array1,array2)` which returns true if array1 ∩ array2 != ∅ and false otherwise.
 One way of solving it would be to make all possible pairs of arrays, and check them for commonality. But the issue here is, given a list of pairs that have common element(s) between them, how to construct the largest subset.
 
e.g. given the above example, how to construct {a1,a2,a4} from (a1,a2), (a1,a4), (a2,a4), (a3,a4).

Comment: Constructing the largest subset from the list of pairs of common sets wouldn't work, as you don't know _what_ is common between them.

Comment: @John if a1 ∩ a2 != ∅ && a1 ∩ a4 != ∅ && a2 ∩ a4 != ∅, then we can have a subset having {a1,a2,a4} because all possible array pairs in this subset have an element in common with each other.

Comment: Consider the case `a1 = {1, 2}; a2 = {2, 4}; a4 = {1, 4}`. We have `a1 ∩ a2 != ∅ && a1 ∩ a4 != ∅ && a2 ∩ a4 != ∅` but still `a1 ∩ a2 ∩ a4 = ∅`.

Comment: True! didn't think about this example.

Comment: @John in scenarios where this intersection hold, can you suggest as how to proceed ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are not interested in finding which particular arrays are in the subset, but rather only the size of the subset, one way would be to create a map of all the possible values to the number of arrays containing that value.

For the example in the question, the map would look something like:

```
count[1] = 1 // contained by a1
count[2] = 1 // contained by a3
count[3] = 2 // contained by a1, a2
count[7] = 3 // contained by a1, a2, a4
count[8] = 2 // contained by a3, a4
count[9] = 2 // contained by a3, a4
```

The highest value in the `count` map (in this case, `3`) is the desired result.

Comment: Can you suggest any other alternative, that should work with object datatypes as well?

Comment: You can use this method, if you can represent an object uniquely with a string/int. Implementation of a map of such objects depends on the language you're using.

Comment: But the structure of object would be a complex/hierarchical one. I don't really want to represent each unique object, but want to simplify the computation by making use of intersection as explained in the question above.

Comment: How do you check whether two objects are equal or not? If you can check that, you can build a map, and an efficient one if you can even compare the objects.